# Under which conditions is the Sobolev constant $S>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $S$ be the optimal Sobolev constant for the Hardy Littlewood Sobolev inequality
$$S||u||_{L^{2^*}} \leq ||(-\Delta)^{s/2}u||_{L^2}$$
where $2^* = \frac{2n}{n-2s}$ where $n>2s$ given by the expression
$$S=S(n, s)=2^{2s} \pi^{s} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2s}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n)}\right)^{2s /n}.$$

I am wondering under what conditions is the constant $S>1?$ I am not familiar with the properties of the gamma function and so I am not sure how to compare the ratios of the gamma function. Any hints/insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start might be Stirlings Formula

Comment: With a plot in WolframAlpha, I get that it is always the case when $n=1$